# Каким образом отправлять POST запрос для формы?

Tags: javascript, php, http, curl, https

Если обрисовать проблему, из которой вытекает вопрос,то все достаточно стандартно : имеется сайт (не мой) с определенной формой , отправляя которую, получаем ответ от сервера в виде данных на той же странице. Мне нужно разобраться, как программно, посредством скрипта отправлять массово запросы с определенными данными по этой форме и получать от него ответ ? Подскажите , пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать и о чем почитать, чтобы решить эту задачу.

Comment: fetch , axios  - смотри это. - это если ajax,   а так ты можешь в форме указать метод отправки и по сабмиту отправлять все введенные данные

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: курлом можно отправлять пост-запросы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываешь инструменты разработчика, панель запросов и смотришь что отправляется, что получается, параметры и все остальное. Если страница перегружается после обработки формы, то ставишь галку "Preserve Log" чтобы не пропадали запросы. Там же можно посмотреть откуда происходит запрос, возможно некоторые параметры формируются как то по особенному. Логику возможно придется повторить.

Далее эмулируешь такой же запрос из скрипта js или php. Из js вряд-ли получится из-за кроссдоменности, а из php вполне возможно. Если будет необходимо, то устанавливаешь хедеры (user-agent, referer и др.). Запрос делаешь с помощью curl или file_get_contents. Еще нужно учесть что могут забанить за слишком частые или подозрительные запросы. Поэтому лучше работать с локальным кэшем во время разработки, чтобы каждый раз не обращаться на сервер.

Также возможно, что необходимо будет сделать несколько запросов чтобы сделать запрос данных. Например, программно залогиниться чтобы получить куки юзера, и уже потом, используя эти куки, делать программный запрос с формы.

Если есть API у сайта, то проще воспользоваться им, а не изобретать велосипед. Например, сервисы гугл. Некоторые сервисы очень сложно эмулируются, например инстаграм, но для популярных сервисов можно поискать готовое решение, даже если оно и не официальное.